# How to find out reason of problems with handlebar bindings?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating application to show users and user's orders. But I don't wan't to add all orders into json response for each user when User model is loading this.store.find('user'). For that I tried to add into json only

```
"links":{ "orders":"order" }
```

And I changed model like that

```
orders: DS.hasMany('order', { async: true })
```

But after that I started to receive errors:

```
Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

I tried to debug and I think it something with handlebars bindings but I amn't sure.

Comment: Can you try reproducing in a jsbin?  Here are some starter templates (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info) some with ember data already in them.